# passing a variable to php file using ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable when a class("women") is clicked using ajax to a php file but it is not working. Here is my code

jquery:

```
$('.women').click(function(){
    var test="hello";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'data.php',
    data: {'variable':test},
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
     $(".women").attr('href','data.php');
})
```

php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['variable']))
{
    echo($_POST['variable']);
}
else
{
   echo ("failure");
}
```

html:

```
<li class="nav-item mr-auto ml-auto" data-target="#collapsewomen">
    <a class="nav-link active women productlink"  href="#">Women</a>
</li>
```

In the console I can see "hello" which mean ajax is working, but once directed to php page I get "failure". What I am not able to pass test variable to php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of ajax is to send data to a URL without refreshing the page. If you want redirect the page, there is no use of using `ajax`.

Doing an `ajax` call will not automatically save the data sent and the data can't be use if you redirect to that page.

**Using GET**

```
$('.women').click(function(){
     var test="hello";
     window.location.href = "data.php?variable=" + test;
})
```

On your php

```
if (isset($_GET['variable']))
{
    echo($_GET['variable']);
}
else
{
   echo ("failure");
}
```

---

**Using POST**, one option is to use hidden form like:

On your main page:

```
$('.women').click(function(){
    var test = "hello";
    $('[name="variable"]').val(test);  //Update the value of hidden input
    $("#toPost").submit();             //Submit the form
})
```

HTML:

```
<a class="nav-link active women productlink"  href="#">Women</a>

<form id="toPost" action="data.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="variable" value="">
</form>
```

On your data.php:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['variable']))
{
    echo($_POST['variable']);
}
else
{
   echo ("failure");
}

?>
```

Comment: great that works pretty fine. I have a question. If I want to use POST instead of GET. How to do it. Is there an explanation why ajax fails

Comment: this will refresh the page with `data.php`  URL. @Ahmed  so using `ajax` is useless then. Normal form processing or link Url will do the job too

Comment: @AlivetoDie That is what I gather from the post. OP do `ajax` and redirect the page after. OP thinks that the data sent in ajax will be saved and used when the page is redirected.

Comment: @Ahmed Will update the post with explanation and post example in a bit

Comment: @Eddie sure thats fine

Comment: @Eddie That great i got your point about ajax. Sorry I am kind to newbie. Any way thanks for the help. Post works pretty fine

Comment: Happy to help. Made the same mistake before :) @Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be data: {variable:test} not data: {'variable':test}

Answer (score 0):

add this to your frontend file

```
<input type="button" class="women" value="Button"  name="ash_b" />

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js" >


$('.women').click(function(){
var test="hello";
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'data.php',
data: {'variable':test},
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
  });
  $(".women").attr('href','data.php');
 })
</script>
```

And in your data.php use following code

```
if (isset($_POST['variable'])) 
 {
   echo($_POST['variable']);
 }
 else
 {
   echo ("failure");
 }
```

it works perfectly for me, try this if this doesnt work show your both files

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
$('.women').click(function(){
var test="hello";
var datastr = 'test='+test; 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'data.php',
data: datastr,
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
  });
  $(".women").attr('href','data.php');
 })
```

Comment: explain little bit about your answer how it address op question?.