# Using Ajax to post a variable to another PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Well, here is my question. So, I have a table, displaying some data using PHP and SQL like this:

[image]

Then, as I showed in that pic, I want to click that button, get the ID value and with that, do another SQL sentence and show another table in another PHP file that I have.

My problem is, that as its mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49642783/passing-a-variable-to-php-file-using-ajax-not-working) you cant really use AJAX to send it and then redirect. And im literally new to AJAX and JavaScript...

Of course, i know other ways like `<form>` and its submit element, but I already have one `<form>` in there, used for displaying the rows of the table, and receive new data input. So if I use form, I would have to nest them, which doesn't work.

I was trying this:

**Table file (Where i have the id that i want to send)**

```
<script>
      function openCateg(id) {
        $.ajax({
            data: {variable: id},
            url: 'categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
            }
        });
        //window.location = "categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php";
      }
    </script>
```

**categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php (Where i wanna receive the data)**

```
 $q = $_POST['variable'];
```

I also tried the GET method, just calling:

```
window.location = "categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?variable=" + id;
```

and

```
 $q = $_GET['variable'];
```

Actually, it did work, but when i reload the site, it doesn't cause the variable becomes null.

**My Table (generated from a SQL sentence in PHP, a basic SELECT**

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return confirm('¿Desea actualizar los datos?')">
        <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered" id ="table" width="70%" border="1px">
          <thead>
            <tr class="w3-theme">
                <th>IDEmpresa</th>
                <th>Usuario</th>
                <th>Nombre*</th>
                <th>Direccion*</th>
                <th>Ambito*</th>
                <th>Color*</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($row as $key => $row) {
                ?>
                <tr class="w3-white">
                    <td><input type="text" class="w3-input" readonly="readonly" name="idE[]" value="<?php echo $row["idEmpresa"]?>" required/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="w3-input" readonly="readonly" name="idU[]" value="<?php echo $row["Usuario"] ?>" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="w3-input" name="nombre[]" value="<?php echo $row["Nombre"] ?>" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="w3-input" name="direccion[]" value="<?php echo $row["Direccion"] ?>" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="w3-input" name="ambito[]" value="<?php echo $row["Ambito"] ?>" required /></td>
                    <td><input type="color" class="w3-input-color" name="color[]" value="<?php echo rgb2hex2rgb($row["Color"]) ?>" /></td>
                    <td >
                      <button id="cat" type="button" name="button[]" class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey w3-hover-light-grey" onclick="openCateg(<?php echo $row["idEmpresa"]?>);">Categorias</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
        <br>
        <div class="w3-center">
          <div class="w3-padding-32">
            <input type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-xlarge w3-dark-grey w3-hover-light-grey" value="Actualizar Empresas" name="update">
          </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

So, in summary, i just wanna click that button showed in the pic, get the id and use it to send it to another file, where i will call a SQL sentence to show another table. 
I would like to redirect to the new php file if possible too.

Just want to send the variable to the other php file without dissapearing when i press the refresh button of the browser.

Excuse my poor English, please...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please show you html table and how you are generating values in the table

Comment: Of course, let me edit my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Comment: I want to redirect. That person doesn't. And im asking for any method that works, just thought AJAX was the best aproach.

Answer (score 0):

If your value becomes null when you refresh then try setting the value which you are passing as default value.

```
document.getElementById("button_id").defaultValue = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want it to be redirected?post your value and get the response,on success you can do everything you want.

```
function OpenCateg(id)
{
variable = id;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?variable="+id,
success: function(data){
window.location = "categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php";

},
error: function(data){ alert('Error occured'); }});}
```

Comment: I want to redirect it when the variable is posted, cause that variable is needed in my other php file to display a new table. Its a button that leads me to all the categories that a company can have. So lets say idEmpresa = 1, then i need that 1 to do a SQL Select to display the categories.

Comment: why use ajax then?

Comment: I don't you need to use ajax at all, just redirect to that page and perform your queries, with the ID still intact

Comment: I thought it was the best aproach, cause i can't really use another form or something like that. If i do it passsing the variable by url, it crashes when refreshing.

Comment: I'm really mixed,and can't see the pic coz my VPN not working right now,you can open session for that ID too

Comment: that means the problem is in the other php page, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 function openCateg(id){
     window.location.assign('categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?id='+id);
 }
```

Comment: Will do, but it's similar to what i posted isn't it? 

`window.location = "categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?variable=" + id;`

Comment: Not yet, but im trying a few things with what you and the others told me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you still redirect to the same *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php* page, then you don't need ajax. Just use hyper-link.
Change this:

```
<td >
    <button id="cat" type="button" name="button[]" class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey w3-hover-light-grey" onclick="openCateg(<?php echo $row["idEmpresa"]?>);">Categorias</button>
</td>
```

To this:

```
<td>
    <a href="categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?variable=<?php echo $row["idEmpresa"] ?>" class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey w3-hover-light-grey">Categorias</a>
</td>
```

Use $_GET array:

```
$q = $_GET['variable'];
```

Also you'll probably have to adjust CSS styles of  element so it would look as your button now, but I think that shouldn't be much problem =)

If page at URL *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php* with *variable* param crashes on reload, then problem should be in this php file. We need it's code here and error message in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: Oh, its not the same page, the table is in a table.php file, and the other one, where i want to send the variable, is the categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php, but i will try this!

Comment: Yes, I think I understood correctly, but didn't explain myself enough. I mean that you do ajax request to *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php* and then after you get responce you redirect to the same *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php*. Or am I wrong? If I'm right, then skip ajax call and just redirect to *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php?variable=ID_HERE* . You may need to adjust code in *categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php* so it handles it like regular http get request, not ajax.

Comment: Oh, i see! You are right then! I will try that, though, i tried similar things and doing it by URL variable makes it dissapear when i refresh, is so strange... Im going to test this tho! Thanks!

Comment: Using this method its better cause I actually can display the data that i wanted, but the refreshing error is still here, and i dont know how to fix this...

Comment: I think that problem is in categoriasSentenciasAJAX.php code. If you post it here, then probably I'll be able to help.